# How to count integers that are greater than a number and then search array to correlate the number to a name

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2010, for-loop

I have two arrays (_intCholesterol and _strPatientNames). What I am trying to accomplish is to look through an array and count the number of integers in the array that are larger than 200, which I have already done below. But additionally I need to search another array (_strPatientName) and correlate the number that was found to be above 200, to a name. Such as Bob 272. And then write the name and high number to a file. How do accomplish the search and correlation?

```
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    Dim objWriter As New IO.StreamWriter("e:/consult.txt")

    For Each intCholesterolLevel In _intCholesterolLevel
        If intCholesterolLevel > 200 Then
            intCount += 1
        End If
    Next

    lblOutliers.Visible = True
    lblOutliers.Text = "There were " & intCount & " people with levels above 200"
```

The code I used ended up being:

```
  Dim objWriter As New IO.StreamWriter("E:\consult.txt")

    ' See if file exists.
    If IO.File.Exists("E:\consult.txt") Then
        ' Run loop for numbers over 200 and write the file.
        For intCholesterolIndex = 0 To (_intCholesterolLevel.Length - 1)
            If _intCholesterolLevel(intCholesterolIndex) > 200 Then
                objWriter.WriteLine(_strPatientName(intCholesterolIndex))
                objWriter.WriteLine(_intCholesterolLevel(intCholesterolIndex))
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox("The file is not available, try again")
    End If

    objWriter.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you may be looking for is a `Dictionary` instead of 2 arrays.

**Possible example**

```
Dim cholesterolLevels As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

cholesterolLevels.Add("Bob", 272)
cholesterolLevels.Add("John", 190)
cholesterolLevels.Add("Joe", 205)
cholesterolLevels.Add("Bill", 165)

For Each patient As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In cholesterolLevels
     Dim name As String = patient.Key 
     Dim level As Integer = patient.Value 

    If level > 200 Then
        intCount += 1
        objWriter.WriteLine(name & " - " & level)
    End if
Next

objWriter.Flush()
objWriter.Close() 

If intCount > 0
    lblOutliers.Visible = True
    lblOutliers.Text = "There were " & intCount & " people with levels above 200"
End if
```